# Check if database exists in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an android app with a sqllite database. This database has various tables. So far I have two tables and I am having an error: when I create the table A first, when I run the code for the table B my app crashes; when I create the table B first and then the A, the app also crashes. I have to clear my app cache so I can "change" the acess, so I'm never able to access both in the same app "run". I think its because Im recreating the database when I add the new table. To avoid that, I tried to check if the database already exists and, if does, not recreate but I'm checking it in the constructor and android doesn't allow it.

log:

> 12-25 00:30:28.024 32031-32031/com.support.android.iplfit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.support.android.iplfit, PID: 32031
>                                                                               android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Dica (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM Dica
>                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1499)
>                                                                                   at com.support.android.iplfit.BDHelpers.DicaBDHelper.removerAllDicasBD(DicaBDHelper.java:73)
>                                                                                   at com.support.android.iplfit.Singletons.SingletonDicas.adicionarDicasBD(SingletonDicas.java:65)
>                                                                                   at com.support.android.iplfit.Singletons.SingletonDicas$1.onResponse(SingletonDicas.java:83)
>                                                                                   at com.support.android.iplfit.Singletons.SingletonDicas$1.onResponse(SingletonDicas.java:77)
>                                                                                   at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
>                                                                                   at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

And one of the classes where Im creating one table:

```
public class DicaBDHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "db_iplfit";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Dica";

    private static final String ID_DICA = "id";
    private static final String CHANNEL_DICA = "channel";
    private static final String TITULO_DICA = "titulo";
    private static final String CONTEUDO_DICA = "conteudo";
    private final SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DicaBDHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

            this.database = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    private static boolean haveDB(Context context, String dbName) {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(dbName);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        String createDicaTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " +
                ID_DICA + " INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY," +
                CHANNEL_DICA + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                TITULO_DICA + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                CONTEUDO_DICA + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ")";
        database.execSQL(createDicaTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int i, int j) {
        String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
        database.execSQL(sql);
        //this.onCreate(database);
    }
}
```

Comment: how exactly are you creating those tables?

Comment: @njzk2 updated the post

Comment: What's wrong with `haveDB()` ?

Comment: @Ibrahim I call it in my constructor like `if(!havedb(context, DB_NAME)){this.database = getWritableDatabase();}` but then I get an error: Variable 'database' might not have been initialized...

Comment: if both databases have the same name, either create the tables in the same helper, or use different database names

Comment: its the same database. So, there is no way to check if it already exists ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to check it. If the data base exists, `onCreate()` will not be called. (`onUpgrade` might be called, but only if you change the database version in your code.) You should eliminate the `database` field from your helper class. Client code should obtain a database instance by calling `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()`.

Comment: @TedHopp So I shoudnt create my tables in the 'onCreate()', right ?

Comment: Yes, and possibly in `onUpgrade()`, depending on how you want to handle version upgrades. (The logic of upgrading will be very specific to your application. It's a common shortcut to just delete the table(s) in the db and call `onCreate()`, but that throws away any existing data.)

Comment: @TedHopp the thing is, I dont know which table will be created first, to manage the version,  they depend on activities. Maybe create all at once on the aplication start ?

Comment: You should create all your tables at the same time, whenever `onCreate()` is called. (You can optionally populate the tables with initial/default values at that time.) An activity will interact with your entire database, not just one table, so the order of activities should never make a difference in how the db is created, just the order in which the tables are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

Use `onCreate` to create multiple tables :-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String createDicaTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " +
            ID_DICA + " INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY," +
            CHANNEL_DICA + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            TITULO_DICA + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            CONTEUDO_DICA + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ")";
    database.execSQL(createDicaTable);

    // Next table
    String createanothertable = "CREATE TABLE anothertable (column TEXT)";
    database.execSQK(createanothertable);
    // etc
}
```

Note! `onCreate` only runs automatically when Database doesn't exist

---

### Option 2

Create subsequent(missing) tables (assumes independence from other other tables) without having to remove existing tables.

Run as required or everytime App is run (hence code `IF NOT EXISTS`).

```
public void addMissingTables() {
    String createanothertable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS anothertable (column TEXT)";
    database.execSQL(createanothertable);
    // etc
}
```

- Note! assumes method is added to Databasehelper (so db)
- Note! Shouldn't be a problem is used after instance of DatabaseHelper is obtained, as `this.database = getWritableDatabase();` will force DatabaseHelper to create database if it doesn't exist.
- You could also code `IF NOT EXISTS` for tables in `onCreate` and call it in a similar fashion.

Comment: I tried the 1st option. So, on the onCreate of each DB class, I reated the others tables along with the present classe table. Is that right ?

Comment: @NelsonSilva Yep, option 2 and the independence is cautioned because the table(s) wouldn't exist until added so extra code would be needed in conjunction with adding the table. The former is the norm.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_FULL_PATH(DB_FULL_PATH is the path to your database file), null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        checkDB.close();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database doesn't exist yet.
    }
    return checkDB != null;
}
```

Comment: that looks like what I have in my haveDB() method, the issues is where to use the verification. Cant do it in the constructor.